# Scripts for form validation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

These are the scripts for a Form and I would like to do the followings:

1. To ensure date, time, no are inputted and selected (no spaces and left empty) which time is an option selection and I don't know how to validate it in myFunction1 `if (isNaN(no) || isNaN(date) || date == "" || no == "" || no == " ")`
2. After ensuring no empty fields that date, time, no are inputted and selected, run this code  `(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0))` to get a result of True or False and return a message respectively

Thanks!

Comment: please add your html as well.

Comment: @Vishalmodi I have added, please take a look, thanks!

Comment: so you are saying that, event after completion of all fields, you are getting message like *Data not completed, please re-enter*

Comment: @Vishalmodi If the fields are not completed "Data not completed, please enter" will be shown. Once all fields are completed, there will be a random generation of 0 or 1 to return True or False and display a message 'Reservation done. Thank you.'  or 'No table is available for the date and time.' respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you have used `isNaN(date)` for date. but you can use it as per your requirement.
Try below solution

```html
<form action="#" method="get" onreset="return check();" ;>
     <fieldset>
     <legend>Reservation</legend>
     <table width="300">
       <caption></caption>
       <thread>
         <tr>
           <th></th>
           <th></th>
         </tr>
     </thread>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Date:</td>
              <td><label><input type="text" id="date" name="date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"></label></td>
            <tr>
              <td>Time:</td>
              <td>
                  <select id="time" name="time:" style="width:173px; height:22px">
                    <option selected="selected">Please select</option>
                    <option>12:00 - 2:00pm</option>
                    <option>2:00pm - 4:00pm</option>
                    <option>4:00pm - 6:00pm</option>
                  </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>No. of Guests:</td>
              <td><label><input type="text" id="no" name="no. of Guests"></label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td id="demo" colspan="2" style="display:none">Data not completed, please re-enter</td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td id="result" colspan="2"></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td><label><button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" name="Check Availability" value="Check Availability" style="width:173px; height:25px">Check Availability</button></label></td>
              <td><label><input type="reset" onclick="myFunction3()" name="Reset" value="Reset" style="width:173px; height:25px"></label></td>
            </tr>
       </tfoot>
   </table>
   </fieldset>
</form>

<script>
   function myFunction() {
         
         function myFunction2() {
        
            if ((arguments.length != 3) && (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0))
                return false
           else return true;
         }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = myFunction1() ? (myFunction2() ? 'Reservation done. Thank you.' : 'No table is available for the date and time.') : '';
   }
</script>
<script>
   function myFunction1() {

        var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
        var no = document.getElementById("no").value;
        var myDiv = document.getElementById("demo");

        if (isNaN(no) || isNaN(date) || date == "" || no == "" || no == " ") {
            myDiv.style.display = "block";
            return false;
        }
        else {
            myDiv.style.display = "none";
            return true;
        }
   }
</script>
<script>
       function myFunction3() {
           document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none";
           document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
       }
</script>
```

Comment: How about ensuring the Time option is selected? Is there anything to do with (arguments.length != 3) and if (isNaN(no) || isNaN(date) || date == "" || no == "" || no == " ") ? @Vishalmodi

Comment: i think that is different from your question, you can refer below link fot it.

https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/javascript-date-validation.php

Answer (score 0):

Return Booleans in function like this:

```
function myFunction(){
    if(myFunction1()) return;
    //If not error in inputed data then continue...
}
function myFunction1(){
    //Check if data is correct or not?
    if(correctData){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true; //wrong data, stop executing myFunction
    } 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="get" onreset="return check();" ;>
 <fieldset>
 <legend>Reservation</legend>
 <table width="300">
   <caption></caption>
   <thread>
     <tr>
       <th></th>
       <th></th>
     </tr>
 </thread>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Date:</td>
          <td><label><input type="text" id="date" name="date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"></label></td>
        <tr>
          <td>Time:</td>
          <td>
              <select id="time" name="time:" style="width:173px; height:22px">
                <option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>
                <option>12:00 - 2:00pm</option>
                <option>2:00pm - 4:00pm</option>
                <option>4:00pm - 6:00pm</option>
              </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>No. of Guests:</td>
          <td><label><input type="text" id="no" name="no. of Guests"></label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="demo" colspan="2" style="display:none">Data not completed, please re-enter</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="result" colspan="2"></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td><label><button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" name="Check Availability" value="Check Availability" style="width:173px; height:25px">Check Availability</button></label></td>
          <td><label><input type="reset" onclick="myFunction3()" name="Reset" value="Reset" style="width:173px; height:25px"></label></td>
        </tr>
   </tfoot>
   </table>
   </fieldset>
</form>

<script>
   function myFunction() {
     if(myFunction1()) return;

     function myFunction2() {
        if ((arguments.length != 3) && (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0))
            return false
       else return true;
     }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = myFunction2() ? 'Reservation done. Thank you.' : 'No table is available for the date and time.';
   }
</script>
<script>
   function myFunction1() {
    var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
    var no = document.getElementById("no").value;
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("demo");
    var time = document.getElementById("time");

    if (isNaN(no) || isNaN(date) || date == "" || time.value == 0 || !time.value || no == "" || no == " ") {
        myDiv.style.display = "block";
        return true; //error
    }
    else {
        myDiv.style.display = "none";
        return false;
    }
   }
</script>
<script>
   function myFunction3() {
       document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none";
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
   }
</script>
```

Comment: How about ensuring the Time option is selected? Is there anything to do with (arguments.length != 3) and if (isNaN(no) || isNaN(date) || date == "" || no == "" || no == " ") ? @RiteshKhandekar

Comment: @nerdy. Add `value = "0"` to first `option` in select(`Please select` option). Then check if `time.value==0` in if statement. I updated my answer.